# vue async call in created() lifecycle hook

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I need to call below method in `created()`. For this purpose, I need to make `created()` as `async`. Per Vue documentation, `created()` is called *synchronously*. Will Vue Framework `await` on `created()` to avoid any race conditions?

```js
this.isAuthenticated = await authService.isAuthenticated();
```

Comment: Posting as comment because it's anecdotal: I've had mixed success in using async with created. For example, making `created` async doesn't fix race conditions when something in `mounted` relies on resolution of an async call in `created`, since `mounted` will begin executing before `created` finishes. 

That said, tacking on `async` to `created()` will not throw and error, and you certainly can use `await` within.

Comment: There's a really long discussion about it on GitHub (async lifecycle hooks). It provides a lot of great discussion around why it would be useful, as well as why it hasn't been done (as of the discussion): https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/7209 ... In case you'd like to read more about it.

Comment: @MattU Before publishing my solution, I searched this thread on Github for a statement by the author of Vue, in which he said that life hooks would be asynchronous. I couldn't find it. Do you associate such a statement?

Comment: This is an antipattern in Angular and React and AFAIK in Vue too. The solution is to move the promise outside the component and don't instantiate it until the promise is fulfilled.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```js
Vue.config.productionTip = false;

function tm(ms, msg) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(msg);
    }, ms);
  });
}

new Vue({
  async beforeCreate() {
    console.log(await tm(1000, "BEFORE CREATE"));
  },
  async created() {
    console.log(await tm(2000, "CREATED"));
  },
  async beforeMount() {
    console.log(await tm(3000, "BEFORE MOUNT"));
  },
  async mounted() {
    console.log(await tm(4000, "MOUNTED"));
  }
}).$mount("#app");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: I'm not so sure this solves the problem. Why would you want to wait that long? And what if the `await`ed call in `created` takes longer than 4s? Then `mounted` will still be called before the `await`ed code returns. Or is that not correct?

Comment: @MattU Actually, this is not the strict answer to the question. I just wanted to show that life hooks work asynchronously. Apparently, such an answer suited the author.

Comment: Fair enough. Apparently so, yes. :)

Comment: I don't think this is actually asynchronous at all. The `tm` calls all happen at about the same time, but the outputs are spaced 1 second apart. So, it only appears asynchronous.

Comment: yes you can do that, the problem is: those are not awaited. So its a bit of a misguided answer. I have seen people do this with webcomponents too.  Having an async function and waiting until its finished are not the same things. In fact, you can put an async function about anywhere, it's just sometimes producing unexpected results, namely when it wasn't anticipated by the caller and therefore not awaited.

Comment: this is incorrect answer, it just looks async and that's all.

Comment: @HumoyunAhmad In that case, I am waiting for your correct answer.

Comment: there is no correct answer in the sense that Vue does not give a component to control its rendering cycle but just lets you hook into the cycle, and that's all. But you can achieve this by using `v-if` condition in the parent component to defer the rendering child component (e.g. waiting promise to be resolved) but this is not an elegant solution and it is course grained control. Here, you can see the upper-hand of React which gives this control mechanism of rendering to the component itself.

Answer (score 1):

If you really need to wait until your asynchronous function is done. You can basically await it before you create the Vue instance. This may not be always useable, but in a case like in this question it is, and it is more solid than putting an asynchronous lifecycle hook that isn't awaited.

```js
Vue.config.productionTip = false;

// mock service
const authService = {
  isAuthenticated: () => new Promise((r) => setTimeout(() => r(true), 2000))
};


// async iife to await the promise before creating the instance
(async() => {
  const isAuthenticated = await authService.isAuthenticated();
  new Vue({
    data: {
      isAuthenticated
    },
    created() {
      console.log('authenticaed:', this.isAuthenticated);
    },
  })
})().catch(console.warn);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```