# How to dynamically import markdown files

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack

I'm building a blog using Vue, where I'd like my posts to be written as markdown files.

Currently I have the following structure

```
src/
  posts/
    blogpost1.md
    blogpost2.md
  view/
    myComponent.vue
```

I want `myComponent.vue` to dynamically load a markdown post based on the route params.

For instance if we visited `.../blog/blogpost2`, then we would dynamically load in `blogpost2.md`

My current implementation is as follows:

```
<template>
    <div
        v-html="md"
    ></div>
</template>

<script>
import marked from "marked";

export default {
    data () {
        return {
            md: undefined,
        };
    },
    created () {
        const importRoute = `posts/blog/${this.$route.params.postName}.md`;
        const md = require(importRoute);
        this.md = marked(md);
    },
};
</script>
```

To load the markdown file I'm using `markdown-loader` in webpack.

I'm also using `copy-webpack-plugin` to try to copy my entire `/posts` dir into my build folder.

```
configureWebpack: {
    module: {
        rules: [{
            test: /\.md$/,
            use: [
                { loader: "html-loader", options: {} },
                { loader: "markdown-loader", options: {} },
            ],
        },
        ],
    },
    plugins: [
        new CopyPlugin({
            patterns: [
                { from: "src/posts", to: "posts" },
            ],
        }),
    ],
},
```

When I run `npm run serve` however, I receive
`[Vue warn]: Error in created hook: "Error: Cannot find module './posts/blogpost2.md'"`

And when I look at the pages in my browser I don't see the `posts` directory (see image below)
[image]

However, when running `npm run build:staging` I do see the `posts` directory in `/dist`

[image]

Why am I unable to import import `blogpost2.md`dynamically?

Comment: Consider reaching for one of the several Markdown site generators that already exist (VuePress, VitePress, Nuxt Content, Gridsome). Don't reinvent the wheel :)

Comment: Yeah I'm seriously considering that but first trying to diagnose why this won't work. I think I'm somehow misunderstanding webpack

Comment: Also worth noting if I make the import reference to blogpost2 a regular string, it works successfully

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My attempt at using a dynamic import that changes based on the route will not work because webpack is unable to properly bundle the imported files. This is because webpack needs to know what it will be importing in order to bundle them correctly.

Instead we can use a different approach of copying our markdown directory as it is into `/dist` and sending a request to fetch each markdown file.

We end up with this in our webpack config (or in my case `vue.config.js`):

```
const CopyPlugin = require("copy-webpack-plugin");

configureWebpack: {
        plugins: [
            new CopyPlugin({
                patterns: [
                    { from: "src/posts", to: "posts" },
                ],
            }),
        ],
    },
```

*Note that we don't need the webpack loaders shown in my initial question because webpack itself isn't handling the loading of these files.*

This ensures that `posts/` gets copied as it is when we build this project.

Then in our component we can dynamically retrieve Markdown files like so:

```
<template>
    <div
        v-html="md"
    ></div>
</template>

<script>
import marked from "marked";

export default {
    data () {
        return {
            md: undefined,
        };
    },
    async created () {
        const res = await fetch(`http://localhost:8081/posts/${this.$route.params.postName}.md`);
        const md = await res.text();
        this.md = marked(md);
    },
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

*// I once need to do a similar thing and faced similar challenges but it was built with Create React App, so please take my answer with a pinch of salt.*

Try placing your import path inside `require(…)` (or `import(…)`, if you ever use it) instead of declaring a variable then passing it in. I remember WebPack has trouble finding files when the paths are not static strings (hard-coded in this way). Whatever dynamic path it may be, your path needs to start with a static string, but you can concatenate dynamic values behind it.

Also, notice the `./` I added to the front of the path. Ignore it if you're using absolute imports, otherwise, this might also be a reason why the code failed?

```js
created () {
    // Instead of:
    // const importRoute = `posts/blog/${this.$route.params.postName}.md`;
    // const md = require(importRoute);
    // Try:
    const md = require(
      `./posts/blog/${this.$route.params.postName}.md`
    );
    this.md = marked(md);
},
```

---

Extra: As much as I know, that the `created` hook in Vue is supposed only be synchronous, but after stumbling upon [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59311495/5810737) I decided to include this snippet too. This one uses dynamic import. If all else fails perhaps you can give this a try?

```js
async created () {
    const { default: url } = await import(
      `posts/blog/${this.$route.params.postName}.md`
    );
    const res = await fetch(url);
    const md = res.text();
    this.md = marked(md);
},
```

Comment: The first answer unfortunately doesn't work because of the way that webpack bundles the code. I don't think it's possible to get it to work this way. The second `extra` that you suggested did in fact work with a bit of tweaking! Will post a more detailed answer explaining